# My select_sort function has any problem can someone give me some suggest?

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
def select_sort(a_list):
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(a_list)):
        minvalue = a_list.index(min(a_list[i:]))
        a_list[i],a_list[minvalue] = a_list[minvalue] , a_list[i]
    return a_list
```

my list is random for test but this function cant sort my list from minimum to max
i want to write a select sort algorithm for practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need two loops for this select sort to work:
How it works - it try to sort an array by repeatedly finding the minimum element  from unsorted part and putting it at the beginning. The algorithm maintains two `virtual subarrays` in a given array. [Note - performance wise, this is not very efficient as it's O(n**2) compared with other more efficient sort algorithm!)

In every iteration of selection sort, the minimum element (considering ascending order) from the unsorted subarray is found and moved to the sorted subarray.

```py
def select_sort(a_list):

   for i in range(len(a_list)):

      # the minimum element position
       min_idx = i

       for j in range(i+1, len(a_list)):
           if a_list[min_idx] > a_list[j]:
               min_idx = j
                
       # Swap the found minimum element with min_idx      
       a_list[i], a_list[min_idx] = a_list[min_idx], a_list[i]

   return a_list

print(select_sort([5,2,1,9,0,4,6]))
```

Comment: This code can work ! I realize this function ~~~

Comment: If it works and helpful, please accept this post and click it?  That's great!

Comment: Oh i forgot ~ i already accept it ! Thanks for your reminder.